# Editable posts WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contenteditable

I'm trying to create my own template in CMS WordPress. I would like to have live editable text on my page http://restaurant.g6.cz/. I want to create something like posts and edit them from the web, because I can't think of anything better. I tried to paste into (page.php) something like

```
<?php
    $my_post = get_post(168);
    echo $my_post->post_content;
?>
```

and tried edit the text with plugin Live Editor but I wasn't successful, so I tried to write

```
<?php query_posts('cat=5&showposts=1'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

this was editable but every post needed it's own category. Does anyone know, how to do this in PHP or better way without plugins? Thank you all very much :)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgfHL.png)

Comment: Load some javascript code when current user is admin (or any role u wish), to add `contenteditable="true"` on each field you want to be edited. In the `js` provide the current post `ID` and do the saving with `wp_ajax` automatically or by clicking a button.

Comment: I've never seen this way, can you help me with it? :)